# PropType check against logic function

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Here's the warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to Row
```

I've written a Grid component which has Rows and Columns.

A Row can accept `children` and I am trying to set this up with PropTypes.

So far I have got:

```
Row.propTypes = {
  size: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
  gap: PropTypes.number,
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element.isRequired)
  ]).isRequired
};
```

Now this works great, until I add a child logic to determine whether to render an additional child.

```
<Row size={1}>
  <Column>
    { title }
  </Column>
  {this.displayComment(item.type) && (
    <Column>
      { comment }
    </Column>
  )}
  <Column>
    { footer }
  </Column>
</Row>
```

The `this.displayComment(item.type)` is throwing the PropType warning. Once removed, it works perfectly.

I then tried to add `PropTypes.func` to the `children` prop type but the warning continues to show.

Comment: why you didn't use .map on list of comments  to render child?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PropTypes.node`. This allows anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array (or fragment) containing these types as well as `null`, `undefined`, and `false`.

> I then tried to add `PropTypes.func` to the children prop type but the
>   warning continues to show.

`PropTypes.func` does not work because you do not pass the function as a child but its return value. You will need to allow `false` to make it work in your example  because `this.displayComment(item.type)` can return `false`.